# Keeping empty column names as such while reading the excel sheet data

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0, oledb

I am reading an excel file and saving contents to database.
I have two columns , first column name is blank and second column name is A.
Both columns has rows under it .

When I am executing `"select * from ["+excel[i]+"]")` using oledbconnection,

empty column is automatically replaced with F1. I need both the columns and data as it is available from excel sheet.

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to avoid this. This is a normal behaviour of OleDB when connected to Excel, if it finds empty columns, it will either take the first row as column name or generate some default names as of F1,F2,F3...etc